# Status bar won't hide if view controller is presented

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have multiple storyboards in my project. I have a home page view controller in one storyboard, and I have a Setup view controller embedded in a navigation controller in a separate storyboard. Now when I Present the setup view controller navigation controller from the homepage view controller, the status bar won't hide. But when I set the setup view controllers storyboard as the main storyboard file base in the info.plist and the setup view controller navigation controller is the first view presented then the status bar will hide. I'm using the code below to hide the status bar. Can someone show me how to hide the status bar when the status view controller is presented  by another storyboard view controller instead of being set as the first view controller. Here is the code I'm using to hide the status bar,

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
      return true  
}
```

Comment: Have you got UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set to true in your info.plist

Comment: I did and it didn't work

Comment: Does this cover your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615647/uiviewcontrollers-prefersstatusbarhidden-not-working

Comment: i added this vc.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true and it didn't work either

Comment: the status bar is still showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide status bar in a condition.. You need to add another Window Object over the status bar.

```
let stautsBarWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
stautsBarWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
//Instead of Presenting just assign your viewController in below line it will hide your statusBar as well.
stautsBarWindow.rootViewController = yourSideMenuViewController
stautsBarWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
stautsBarWindow.isHidden = false
```

Comment: which view controller do i place this in. The one in the navigation controller or the home page view controller

Comment: ViewController that you have presented.  instead of presenting just give the viewControllers object below.

Comment: so i don't present the navigation controller.

Comment: thats your solution

Comment: figured it out. Thanks